# How to move a column in Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs

I know how to do this in Google Spreadsheets, but it seems there's no data moving support for tables in Google Documents at all. (I can't even select in columns)

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've tried a lot. You can't move the columns of a table in the Documents of GDocs. However, if you create a column to the left or right or where you want the new column, you can then select the content from the column you want to move, copy, then, and this is important, you have to select the whole new (blank, newly created) column from top to bottom, and paste the material there. Then, delete the old column and the table will re-format the size. Good luck!!

Comment: This is still the case in 2020 which seems odd given Google's apparent capability at building web applications...They can build a search engine but you can't move a column in a document!

Answer (score 1):

1. click the column
2. ctrl-c or command-c to copy
3. right click column where you want to move it , 
   select "Insert 1 right"
4. ctrl-v or command-v to paste 
   done.

Comment: That might work in Sheets, but that doesn't work in Docs.

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternative 1. Create a new column and paste the contents into it

As already explained in
[this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/48477)
you can create a new column and then copy-paste the contents
from the source column to the new empty column.
Finally, delete the no longer wanted column.

*To create a new column*
Right-click any cell next to where you want the new column to appear
and choose either *Insert column left* or *Insert column right*.
Copy-paste the contents.

*To delete the old column*
Right-click any cell in the no longer wanted column and (left-)click
*Delete column*.

#### Alternative 2. Create a Google spreadsheet and link it to Google Docs

The above solution works fine, but I prefer a slightly different
method :

- I create the table in a Google Sheets spreadsheet.
- Then I link the stylesheet table to the Google Docs document.

*Instructions in more detail*
In the Google spreadsheet, I (left-)click the cell at the bottom-right
of the table.
Then I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and keep it down, and hit the left arrow
<kbd>←</kbd> until all columns are selected.
Still keeping the <kbd>Shift</kbd> down, I press and keep the up arrow
<kbd>↑</kbd> down until all columns are selected.
<sup>1</sup>

Next I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, then open the Google Docs
document, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> where I want the
table.
<sup>2</sup>

I leave *Link to spreadsheet* checked and click Paste.

[image: Link the spreadsheet to the Google Docs document.]

The table is now linked from Google Sheets to Google Docs.
This means that whenever I make a change in the Google Sheets
table, I'm offered to <kbd>UPDATE</kbd> the linked table in
Google Docs.
<sup>3</sup>

[image: Google offers to update a linked table when it's changed.]

#### Reference

- [Solution on how to move a column in Google Docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/48477)
- [Google Drive documents keyboard shortcuts for Windows and macOS](https://www.howtogeek.com/440067/all-the-best-google-sheets-keyboard-shortcuts)

---

<sup>1</sup>
There might be other (more elegant) ways to do it,
but this works for me.

<sup>2</sup>
[On macOS just press <kbd>⌘</kbd>](https://www.howtogeek.com/440067/all-the-best-google-sheets-keyboard-shortcuts/)
whenever I write <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

<sup>3</sup>
For example, in the Google Sheets table, I can click a column
letter and drag the column to the left or the right whichever
I want.

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to move it at first, but if I double click on column name and drag it, I could see a black line border at the left edge of the column and when I drag it across the other columns, I was actually able to move it.

Comment: I think you're talking about Google Spreadsheets. I have no trouble moving columns there. The problem is with Google Documents where I cannot even select a whole column.

Comment: aren't they both same?

Comment: You certainly won't consider Excel and Word the same application, will you?

Comment: Okay, so you have a column in document writer, I get it now

Answer (score -2):

I've just checked and selecting both row and columns is allowed.
Right clicking over selected column (or row) shows cut, copy, paste an a few other options.
You should check any restriction on your web browser. Maybe trying with another one.

Comment: Tried Firefox and Chromium under Linux and neither of them supports column selection. Are you sure you did it in document as opposed to spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm positive on a Windows enviroment, since I don't have any Linux desktop around I can't test it. Do you have the same problem using the live demo? http://www.google.com/google-d-s/spreadsheets/

Comment: That's the 'spreadsheet' app of Google Docs. I am using the 'document' app...

Comment: You should try clearning your cache and trying again. I know that I used to have problems with Google Docs in linux and I needed to clear my cache often. It also could be an issue with the size of document combined with the OS.